# How to fix Depricated Api error on Android studio

Tags: java, android

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,Language_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        },1500);
```

Comment: Use LifeCycleScope...

Comment: *"Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details."* - What did it say when you did that?

Comment: when i press build, there is one warning showing like this

Comment: Use ```new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())```